# psql on windows: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc8 0x20

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

on `database1`:

- `show LC_CTYPE;` shows `C`
- `show LC_COLLATE;` shows `C`
- `show SERVER_ENCODING;` shows `UTF8`

but `set "PGPASSWORD=password1" & set "PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8" & psql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -d database1 -c "INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES ('mise à jour 1');"`

shows: `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc8 0x20`

the error disappears if `PGCLIENTENCODING` is set to `ISO_8859_5` for example

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing much to fix. Your Windows shell uses a different encoding than UTF-8, so you have to set the client encoding to that encoding to make it work. To find out which client encoding to use, you must figure out which encoding your shell uses. That in turn depends on which shell you are using and how the Windows system was configured.